# Why the eBay FindingService response 'Invalid product ID value', but product with such EAN really exists?

Tags: ebay-api

I try to search some product details by eBay API, I meet a problem.
For some EAN, the product really exist in eBay' page, for example, a movie:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/The-Shawshank-Redemption-DVD-NEW-/281073136687?hash=item417143b42f:g:Kd0AAOSwq5lTq3wI
[By the Way, I got the movie's ebay page by google "site:ebay.com 9325336105405"]

When I use the eBay API to find the product
(e.g. click: http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=Your_App_ID_Goes_Here&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&globalId=EBAY-AU&productId.@type=EAN&productId=9325336105405)

I got such xml response:

`<findItemsByProductResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <ack>Failure</ack>
    <errorMessage>
        <error>
        <errorId>41</errorId>
        <domain>Marketplace</domain>
        <severity>Error</severity>
        <category>Request</category>
        <message>Invalid product ID value.</message>
        <subdomain>Search</subdomain>
        <parameter>9325336105405</parameter>
        </error>
    </errorMessage>
    <version>1.13.0</version>
    <timestamp>2016-03-12T08:10:35.039Z</timestamp>
</findItemsByProductResponse>`

And when I type the EAN in the seachbox of eBay website, eBay says:

**This listing (9325336105405) has been removed, or this item is not available.**
**Please check that you've entered the correct item number**
**Listings that have ended 90 or more days ago will not be available for viewing.**

I am sure this is a correct EAN, and this product have not been ended, It still has a button 'Buy it now'.
Since the EAN starts with '932' meas that is a Australia product, so I try to search it on www.ebay.com.au, and get the same response.

**Why the eBay API treat such EAN as invalid?

How could I fetch the details of this EAN by eBay API?**
Thanks a looooooot!!!

Comment: Couple things.. First off, your second link bails out with an authentication error, so it isn't going to be useful to us to troubleshoot.  Second thing.. the Product ID is the eBay Product ID I believe?  That would be the number at the top right of the item specifics section of the page.  I think the EAN is a unique item specifics value.  That could be why it is registering invalid ID..

Comment: I am incorrect on my previous comment.  You do in fact search by EAN using ProductID with Type=EAN which it appears you have done.

Comment: Upvote on this because you SHOULD be able to search by EAN using the command you implemented above, but it appears that it doesn't work.

Comment: Up-voting because I'm having the same issue: I have a valid EAN, but get the same error response.

Answer (score 4):

Use the findItemsAdvanced call, and put the EAN in keywords and you will get a good response.

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=<Your AppID>&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&globalId=EBAY-US&keywords=9325336105405
```

[Similar Issue Here](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/11699/errorid-14-invalid-numeric-value-when-search-by-pr.html)

Comment: Thank you @Nate M. Your advice is really helpful. I have voted up for your answer.